# using dplyr inner join where the variable being joined on is a variable

Tags: r, join, dplyr

If I wanted to join two tables a and b using a column (call it x), i'd do the following:

```
ab <- a %>%
inner_join(b, by = "x")
```

Let's say I wanted x to be a variable that the user could input to control what column to join on. How would I do this?

Comment: You can pass a variablee `var1 <- "x"; a %>% inner_join(b, by = var1)`

Comment: What kind of user?

Comment: Will the same thing work when I'm trying to group_by multiple columns including a variable?
eg.
var1 <- "x"
ab <- a %>%
group_by(col1, var1)

Comment: But, isn't that a different question.  You can use `group_by_at(vars('col1', var1))`. or `group_by(col1, !! rlang::sym(var1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
ab <- a %>%
inner_join(.,b, by = "x")
```